# Transferring data from Javascript to python

Tags: javascript, python, google-app-engine

I am adding google sign in to my website. For this purpose i have used the following code for the front end in JavaScript:

```
<script>
function onSuccess(googleUser) {
    var profile = googleUser.getBasicProfile();
    gapi.client.load('plus', 'v1', function () {
        var request = gapi.client.plus.people.get({
            'userId': 'me'
        });
        //Display the user details
        request.execute(function (resp) {
            var profileHTML = '<div class="profile"><div 
class="head">Welcome '+resp.name.givenName+'! <a href="javascript:void(0);" 
onclick="signOut();">Sign out</a></div>';
            profileHTML += '<img src="'+resp.image.url+'"/><div 
class="proDetails"><p>'+resp.displayName+'</p>
<p>'+resp.emails[0].value+'</p><p>'+resp.gender+'</p><p>'+resp.id+'</p><p><a 
href="'+resp.url+'">View Google+ Profile</a></p></div></div>';
            $('.userContent').html(profileHTML);
            $('#gSignIn').slideUp('slow');
        });
    });

}
function onFailure(error) {
    alert(error);
}
function renderButton() {
    gapi.signin2.render('gSignIn', {
        'scope': 'profile email',
        'width': 240,
        'height': 50,
        'longtitle': true,
        'theme': 'dark',
        'onsuccess': onSuccess,
        'onfailure': onFailure
    });
}
function signOut() {
    var auth2 = gapi.auth2.getAuthInstance();
    auth2.signOut().then(function () {
        $('.userContent').html('');
        $('#gSignIn').slideDown('slow');
    });
}

</script>
```

Now i want the user's information from their google account to be transferred to my back end server code written in Python 2.7 so that user can login to my website using those credentials. My web application is deployed in GAE. I have no idea how should i proceed or what libraries should i use.

Comment: have a look at Cloud Endpoints https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/python/

Comment: show us attempts. the current code shows no attempts or what went wrong, thus too broad.